# Callbacks type different

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

Whats the difference between:

in `RCTComponent.h`:

```
RCTDirectEventBlock
RCTBubblingEventBlock
```

And

in `RCTBridgeModule.h`:

```
RCTResponseSenderBlock
RCTResponseErrorBlock
RCTPromiseResolveBlock
RCTPromiseRejectBlock
```

Basically, What I need to consider when I choose the right callback I want to run back in the `JavaScript`?